# Convert VfW-codec based video to "normal" (Windows)

Tags: conversion, windows, codec

my CCTV software (GeoVision) supplies me with AVI videos with the FourCC "GMP4" codec ("Geovision MP4"). The codec is supplied as a Video for Windows 32-bit driver only, so I had to set up a virtual machine to even be able to play the files with MPC-HC. What software can I use to convert the files into something more universal like h.264?
The "usual suspects" ffmpeg/VLC don't play the file at all because they are not able to use VfW codecs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While it can't go direct to H.264, VirtualDub I believe can work with Vfw codecs and can transcode to something more compatible with your other tools.  I don't know if Quicktime for Windows supports Vfw codecs or not, but I do believe the Pro version of Quicktime supports H.264 encoding.

If you have Adobe Media Encoder, it would also easily do what you are looking for, but I believe it only comes with the Adobe suite, thus would be prohibitively expensive if you don't have it already.